# append row with offset function to populate data to correct cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to populate and get data to/from Google Sheets from/to the google web app.
So far, it is doing what it intended to.
But the issue is that I do not want to get data to the last row; instead, I want to put data to the selected row and column.

here is the code

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e){

 Logger.log(e.parameter);
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form").evaluate();


}

function formSbmt(formInfo){
 var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c4K-kkzxJPDiCYS4xcD2X7rKR8c_9pYqp9N4vtEEybE/edit#gid=0";
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
 var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

 ws.appendRow([null,null,formInfo.orderDate,null,null,formInfo.orderNo,formInfo.orderSrc]);

}

function include(filename){
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();


}
```

HTML

```
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class="center">Order Form</h2>
    <div class="fr">
    <label for="odate">Order Date</label>
    <input type="date"id="odate"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="fr">
      <label for="onum">Website Order</label>
      <input type="number"id="onum"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="fr">
      <label for="wsrc">Source</label>
      <select id="wsrc">
        <option>NAJ</option>
        <option>JAJ</option>
        <option>FJ</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="fr">
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <?!= include("page-js"); ?>
  </body>
```

i separated the Javascript by creating an include function

Script-js

```
<script>

      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",sclicked);

      function sclicked(){
        var formInfo = {};

         formInfo.orderDate = document.getElementById("odate").value;
         formInfo.orderNo = document.getElementById("onum").value;
         formInfo.orderSrc = document.getElementById("wsrc").value;


         google.script.run.formSbmt(formInfo);
         document.getElementById("odate").value = "";
         document.getElementById("onum").value = "";
         document.getElementById("wsrc").value = "";


      }
      
      
    </script>
```

the thing is that it is populating the data on the last available row. but I have some data in already as well as in column 0 1 and so on

I wanted to put the data in row 552 and columns 2, 5, and 6, and so on, with some exceptions of columns.

PS: I do have mode columns in the sheet which I need to populate in the same form just wanted to experiment with few columns before going full sheet.

[image: Here is my google sheet]
[image: This is my webapp]

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c4K-kkzxJPDiCYS4xcD2X7rKR8c_9pYqp9N4vtEEybE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: When you say `I want to put data to the selected row and column`, do you mean put the data to whatever row is currently selected in your sheet? For example, if `D3` is selected, data will be written to `C3`, `F3` and `G3`? Also, is the script [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the spreadsheet?

Comment: No i want to go in sequence but start after a specific row for 1st data then it will go in sequence,

Comment: What does this mean? You want to write to the first row with empty C, F, G cells?

Comment: No. i want to start it from row 523 with C F G empty for each new record

Comment: It's unclear for me what you want to accomplish. Please consider expanding on your description.

Comment: I dont know how to explain more. my question is almost clear. :(

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

Get the last row with content according to column C and start pasting from column C.

- This approach assumes that column C does not have blank cells in between, and the values start from cell C1.

### Solution:

**Change:**

```
 ws.appendRow([null,null,formInfo.orderDate,null,null,formInfo.orderNo,formInfo.orderSrc]);
```

**to:**

```
 var cLength = ws.getRange("C1:C").getValues().filter(String).length;
 var data = [formInfo.orderDate,null,null,formInfo.orderNo,formInfo.orderSrc];
 ws.getRange(cLength+1,3,1,data.length).setValues(data);
```

Comment: i pasted your code and it returned nothing

Comment: @AliAhmed I will repeat what is already in my answer but just to emphasize it. 1) Do you have blank cells in column C? 2) Do the values start from row 1 in colulmn C or a different row? Alternatively, provide a copy of your sheet (remove sensitive info) so I can see your sheet. As you may understand, It is really difficult to provide an answer if you can't see the sheet.

Comment: I update the link to my sheet. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AliAhmed in the script editor the code is not related to your question. Can you update the code?

Comment: updated the code. sorry i am new to all this.

Comment: @AliAhmed you didn't update it.. Did you click on save?

Comment: i dont know its saying your post almost has code. please define.

Comment: i will re write in the morning

Comment: @AliAhmed still you haven't updated your code. https://script.google.com/home/projects/15bejIYIHDn9acs-KrB9VKdG0OlCXUSIFYMI7qw5_yCfmJdjC1anpis1E/edit

Comment: it is not letting me to to do so